# Mail browser has 20+ viewer windows open but can't close them all, even with a force restart

Tags: email

When I click show all viewer windows, they pop up on the bottom and allow me to pick one by one to close them. Is this my only option to close them all?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime, can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/350875/edit) your question to clarify what email client you're using? At present your question title only refers to "Mail browser", but that's a very generic term.

Answer (score 1):

`Command + Option + W` closes all the Windows on the app.

One may also click on `File` menu at the top, and hold `Option` key to find the `Close all` option to close all windows.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on your goal? My understanding was that you want to close all the windows on the app (Mail app).